# Is this function atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic, nonblocking

I have a use case where I need to add values to an underlying datastructure and the order needs to be maintained. I am using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` as the underlying datastructure. Following is the function

```
public void put(V value) {
   concurrentLinkedQueue.add(value); 
}
```

Is this statement atomic, in the sense if two threads are trying to put values, Thread A first (value V1) and Thread B second (value V2), is there a possibility V2 will be added first and V1 later.

Comment: We may be able to answer your question if you could exactly define the meaning of the word **first** in the sense of a multi-threading environment?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon by first, the first thread that calls `put`.

Comment: @user592748 - What if they both call at **exactly** the same time - in a multithreading and multicore environment that can happen.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I get updates and I need the order maintained. My concern is that I should not have what i consider the latest update to be stale. In the case you mention, an arbitrary order is tolerable.

Comment: @user592748 - Then you should time-stamp your updates to maintain order. You should never rely on an undocumented feature of a language.

Comment: The get only values and I need to version it. That I cannot change.

Comment: The only sensible meaning for "first" in this context is that that call to `add` returned before the other thread's call to `add` could possibly have occurred. If you ensure this somehow, then yes. If not, then no. (By the way, this isn't about atomicity, it's about ordering. Between threads, you only have ordering you create somehow.)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, when reasoning about multi-processor machines, there is no need to say "at the same time".  The memory system will never allow two stores to the same location to happen at the same time, and for any other kind of event, three possibilities are sufficient to prove whatever needs to be proved:  Either we can prove that A happens before B, or we can prove that B happens before A, or we can't tell and it doesn't matter.

Comment: @avk, I could say, it's not a procedure, it's a _method_.  Actually, we have lots of names for what it is:  Routine, subroutine, handler, procedure, method, function, subprogram, callable unit, and I don't know what else.  What we call it depends on where we come from.  If you practice functional programming, then you probably reserve the word "function" for named routines that do not alter the state of any object.  If you are most familiar with any Smalltalk-inspired language, then you never say "function" and always say "method", and if you are a C programmer, then they're all "functions."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that your question is kind of meaningless.

If two threads call `put` in an unsynchronized way, then there's no observable difference between

```
Thread 1     Thread 2

put          
add
             put
             add
```

and

```
Thread 1    Thread 2

put          
             put
             add
add
```

Even if you make the method `synchronized` you'll have a data race in your program unless you introduce proper happens-before relations between the two actions.

Ask your self *why* the order in which the threads call `put` is important, and make sure that this intention is captured by proper synchronization.

Comment: is there a way to maintain the order without a blocking function? Can you elaborate on introducing proper happens-before relation

Comment: This is the thing: Suppose thread 1 gets triggered to call put, then quickly after, thread 2 gets triggered to call put. But out of pure bad luck, the OS/JVM happens to schedule thread 2 instead of thread 1. This leads to having thread 2 reach add before thread 1. Now, what can you do about this? Formally speaking, not much! The only solution I can think of is to try to make it single threaded (you could probably use selectors from the nio package for instance) or add time stamps to your values, so they can be ordered.

Comment: Ask yourself, what *should* happen if Thread 1 is triggered just a nano-second before Thread 2? Is it even "your fault" if you log the events in the opposite order? Will anyone for sure be able to tell you, "hey, I sent you those two values in the opposite order!"? If anyone actually can, *how* did they know this? Is there an inherent time stamp in the messages? If so, take advantage of that on your side as well! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Background: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is thread safe in implementation. And it is FIFO. So it will maintain the insertion order.

The answers to your questions:

> Is this statement atomic

Yes

> Is there a possibility V2 will be added first and V1 later

Yes

If you want the Thread A to insert value before the Thread B, then you need to implement routines to explicitly handle the insertion order. Atomicity of the add operation in `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` has nothing to do with it. It all depends on which thread calls the add() method first.

If you want to maintain order (i.e. - FIFO) multi threading could not be your answer. May I ask why do you need multi-threaded execution? I can think of a few situations which you will need multi-threading with FIFO order. Simply because you are trying to process ordered data in parallel which cannot be guaranteed to finish processing in the same order.

If by chance it is absolutely necessary to user parallel processing you can use a popular thread configuration like the following:

1. You can have a Manager-worker system where the manager thread obtains the job, and delegates it to a pool of worker threads which will do the processing and re-sequence the results based on some property in the job's data structure (i.e.- timestamp, sequence number).

[image]

2. You can have a delegator thread which will obtains the job, and delegates it to a pool of worker threads which will do the processing and submit the results to another thread which will perform the re-sequencing based on some property in the job's data structure (i.e.- timestamp, sequence number).

[image]

Inside the Manager or Output Sequencer threads you may have to maintain data buffers which will hold the data before sequenced for dispatching.

As you can see, an implementation like this could be quite complex. So you have to ask yourself, 'do you really need to process the data in parallel?'.